# How to target an element in a different window, same domain?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to target a hidden element in one html document from a completely different, independent document? They are both on the same domain, but not in any way related to one another. One sets up some variables and the other just looks for those changes. I have a hidden input element in page2.html. That page is loaded and uses an AJAX call every 10 seconds to look for changes made by page1.html.

I need to target page2.html using a javascript file loaded in page1.html then change the value in that hidden input. Can this be done? I can do this server-side but this way seems a little easier if it's possible. This is JavaScript not JQuery.

Comment: How are the windows related? Did one open the other with window.open()? If yes, it is as simple as using the window reference.

Comment: They are in no way related, other than they both share the same project directory. One form is opened independently from the other. This is what makes it difficult for me to get my head around. I'm not a JavaScript expert by any stretch so I thought I'd ask here before starting to use backend code to set the element

Comment: Then there is no way for them to reference each other if they are not opened from the same document.  You could write to local storage from the one and have the other check for it.

Comment: So, if computer1 has page1.html open and sets a local storage variable, will computer2 running page2.html be able to access the local storage set by computer1.page1?

Comment: oh.... it is two computers.... no. You need server side code

Comment: Okay, thanks epascarello. From what I'm reading now, this looks like the right answer. Unless anyone else can provide a JavaScript solution, I'll accept this as the right answer if you post it below.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this via [signalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client)

So in one page you send the signalR notification with whatever information you need. And on the other page you create a signalR listener which listens for notifications and displays the transmitted information.

So on the server you will need to setup a Hub to listen and emit events.

Comment: Thanks. After a quick glance, it looks like it might take more time to set up, after implementing Visual Studio than it would take me to use back-end code to set the element in the HTML.

Comment: It is a useful technology to learn nevertheless

Comment: Absolutely, I agree.